# How do I change my Windows 10 administrator sign-in name?

Tags: windows-10, login, microsoft-account

I recently read that running Windows (10 Home, in my case) primarily on an administrator account is a bad idea for security reasons. So, I created a local account to work in, and I'll only log in as an administrator as needed.

My administrator account displays my real name on the sign-in screen. *I'd like to change this to just "Administrator" or "Administrator Jack" to differentiate the two accounts*, since my local account is also my full name.

I can't figure out how to do this. I logged into my Microsoft account, which is linked with the machine's administrator account, and changed my name there, but the change has not taken effect on the sign-in screen; it still shows my full name.

What do I need to do to make these desired changes?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

- Open **Control Panel**
- Click the **Change account type** link
- Select the account you want to modify
- Click the **Change the account name** link
- Type the new name for the account
- Click the **Change Name** button.

The sign-in screen should now display the new account name you specified.

Comment: The "Change the account name" option is not available for my administrator account. It's only an option for my local account.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out thanks to [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VpEagxSWzX0). Here are the steps I performed:

1. Run a command prompt (as administrator)
2. To activate Windows' admin account, type: `net user administrator /active:yes`
3. To set a password, type: `net user administrator *`

And it worked. I now have an account named **Administrator.**

Comment: The default name to the built-in account is already Administrator.  This is not the proper solution to your question.  The built-in Administrator account should not be used routinely.  It’s disabled by default for a reason.  What should be done is your User account should be linked to your Microsoft Account and your existing Administrator account should be converted to a local account.  This will allow you to change the name of your existing Administrator account.  The built-in account has slightly different permissions then your created Administrator account.

Comment: Just so I understand you correctly: I should keep the build-in Administrator account hidden. When I first fire up my Windows machine and create an account, that's the existing Administrator account, which should be a local account. So, I need to create another account, a User account, which should be linked to my Microsoft account. Is that right? Right now I have the build-in Administrator account enabled, but I don't plan on logging into it unless there are serious issues. I'm using a User account, which is linked to a Microsoft account. Am I asking for trouble by working this way?